# Basement rough-in PVC drain pipe is not centered with stud

Tags: drain, studs, pvc

Our basement rough-in PVC drain pipe is not centered with the wall studs. It is not a load bearing wall since it's a newly framed wall (*wall can no longer be moved*). We now have to extend the drain to the vanity sink which is 3 ft out with two studs in between.

Can I angle a 3 ft long 1.5 inch pipe slightly to fit through the next two studs as centered as possible?

What are my options?

[image]

[image]

[image: Basement rough-in PVC drain pipe is not centered with stud]

Comment: The biggest problem I see is that it appears that the flanges on that sani-tee are sticking out past the face of the stud which means that the wall board won't sit flat. What problem are _you_ trying to solve? Maybe include an extra pic, or draw some lines on your pic to indicate what you're talking about.

Comment: Correct. That's the issue. Looks like I can only attach one picture? We need to extend the pipe from the sani-tee with 3 ft to the left along the framed wall. There are two studs where I would need to drill a hole to run the pipe to the sink, but the sani-tee sticks out past the stud and will stick out the next two studs as well, unless I angle it to have it centered. Otherwise I would have to chop the outside of the studs to fit the pipe?

Comment: How long is the wall with the issue?  Would it be practical to fur out the studs to make more room? I'm not a framer so others may not think this is a good idea.  When I built my house, I went with 2x6 for even the interior walls just to make room for all the utilities. Hardly any nail plates needed!

Comment: I was able to add another picture. Wall is only 5 ft long. Pipe needs to run along two studs (3 ft) to get to P-trap. We were thinking off furring out as one of the options.

Comment: @WilliamLee  Glad that's an option. For such a short wall, that's what I would do.

Comment: @williamlee do you need to line the other side of the wall at all?  (ie the side you're on in the third photo)   If its a garage then it may be acceptable to leave the wall open with the pipe proud and visible.  If you want to line it, then it gets messy but achievable with packing/furring, or probably adding some 2x1 beside every framing member (sistering, I guess?)  You'll loose some room space, but could choose to embed some recesses/niches where convenient for storage.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a pair of 11.25, 15 or 22.5 degree bends back to back to offset the pipe.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping you could do that. Would that be allowed per code?

Comment: There's no inherent code problem, though you can certainly screw it up into a code violation if you offset too much vertically without providing a vent line, or such that water has to flow uphill.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, drill holes in the studs.  Use a 2" hole saw to get a 1.5" DWV line over to the sink.  That means you need to install metal protection plates on both sides to protect the pipes, too.  If you have a drill with a side handle, that will help.  I use my hammer-drill with the hammering turned off.

When planning the holes, plan for a 1/4"-per-foot slope so the drain works properly.  Be sure to use a true level, like a bubble level, as a reference.  Don't simply measure from the floor because floors aren't always level (especially in basements.)

If the hole doesn't come out right the first try, don't be afraid to use a chisel or reciprocating saw to adjust it.  You don't need perfection here; you just need the pipe to go through the studs at approximately the right slope.  If it ends up having a bunch of play in it, add a pipe hanger to hold it where you want.

Comment: My problem is that the pipe will not line up with the center of the studs. It's sticking out at the sanit-tee. See latest picture.